# DataGridTextColumn with ValidatesOnDataErrors = true Requires Values to be Added Twice

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, idataerrorinfo

I have a column in a WPF DataGrid bound to an object with the following members:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the Value property. This observable property 
/// indicates ....
/// </summary>
public double Value
{
    get { return _scalarData.Value; }
    set
    {
        if (_scalarData.Value.EqualsWithPrecision(value)) return;

        _scalarData.Value = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Value);
    }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        if (columnName == "Value")
        {
            if (Value < _scalarElement.MinValue || Value > _scalarElement.MaxValue)
            {
                return "Value must be between the min and max value";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The column is dynamically generated in the Codebehind (for other reasons related to the specifics of the app):

```
else if (e.PropertyType == typeof(ScalarDataEntryViewModel))
{
    column = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName + "." + "Value")
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
            ValidatesOnDataErrors = true,
            Converter = new DoubleToPersistantStringConverter()
        }
    };
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem appears anywhere you use a DataGridTextColumn with ValidatesOnDataErrors set to true.

If you start with invalid values (perhaps because it's a new row or for some other reason) the grid correctly highlights the cells containing errors. The problem is, when you enter a cell and update the value, when focus leaves the row, the value is reverted back to its original (invalid) value. If you re-enter the cell and re-change the value, it works fine. But for each invalid cell, you must enter the new value twice.

If I comment out the error checking on "this[string columnName]" or set ValidatesOnErrors = false, the problem goes away, but I don't get highlighted cells.

I can use custom templates (a TextBlock and TextBox) as a workaround, but this brings with it its own quirks so I would rather get the built in templates working properly.

How do I make this function as expected, so that I have only to enter a value once?

Comment: What happens when you don't set the UpdateSourceTrigger (leave it as UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus)?